# Firebase messaging service worker click handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

I am using FCM to handle push notifications, but notification is coming in `data` key instead of `notification`.

Here is the code I am using to handle new message and show as notification.
I am seeing notification with all options and data as I specified. However, when I click notification, it doesn't fire any "notificationclick" event. It also doesn't print `event.notification`.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "SOME_ID",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
    console.log(payload);
    const options = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: payload.data.icon,
        click_action: payload.data.click_action,
        link: payload.data.link,
        data: {
            time: new Date(Date.now()).toString(),
            click_action: payload.data.click_action,
        },
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, options);

});



self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
    console.log(event.notification);
    const clickedNotification = event.notification;
    clickedNotification.close();

    const urlToOpen = clickedNotification.data && clickedNotification.data.click_action;

    const promiseChain =  clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true,
    })
        .then((windowClients) => {
            let matchingClient = null;

            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
                    matchingClient = windowClient;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchingClient) {
                return matchingClient.focus();
            } else {
                return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
            }
        });

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

});
```

Comment: Are you using the admin firebase API or the legacy ones? Does the console statement confirm that setBackgroundMessageHandler is actually being called?

Comment: @nuruddin-iminokhunov any luck with the solution for click handling? Struggling with same issue.

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: Why everyone asking this problem, but no solution at all?

Answer (score 2):

Move the notificationclick event Listener on top before the firebase code, that should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1 you can check with your firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the application whether the recent changes are in that file after the build.

2 we only need the most recent changes in firebase-messaging-sw.js, so need to check and most recent updated firebase-messaging-sw.js file and unregister all older firebase-messaging-sw.js.

it worked for me.